# SelectOneMenu PrimeFaces

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, enums

```
<h:body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <h2>Create</h2>
        <h:form id="frm">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Doctor</h4>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel class="control-label col-md-2" for="name"
                    value="Name" />
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p:inputText class="form-control text-box single-line" id="name"
                        name="name" value="" placeholder="Ex: John Smith"
                        autofocus="true" maxlength="100" required="true"></p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel class="control-label col-md-2" for="address"
                    value="Address"></h:outputLabel>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p:inputText class="form-control text-box single-line"
                        id="address" name="address" type="text" value=""
                        placeholder="Ex: Fifth Avenue" maxlength="100" required="true"></p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel class="control-label col-md-2" for="cpf" value="CPF"></h:outputLabel>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p:inputMask class="form-control text-box single-line" id="cpf"
                        name="cpf" value="" maxlength="14"
                        placeholder="Ex: 999.999.999-99" required="true"
                        mask="999.999.999-99"></p:inputMask>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel class="control-label col-md-2" for="phone"
                    value="Phone"></h:outputLabel>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p:inputText class="form-control text-box single-line" id="phone"
                        name="phone" type="tel" value="" placeholder="Ex: (99)9999-9999"
                        maxlength="15" required="true"></p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel class="control-label col-md-2" for="crm" value="CRM"></h:outputLabel>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p:inputText class="form-control text-box single-line" id="crm"
                        name="crm" type="number" min="1" max="1000" step="10" value="" placeholder="Ex: 1234"
                        maxlength="4" required="true"></p:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h:outputLabel class="control-label col-md-2"
                    value="Type"></h:outputLabel>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="type" name="type" value="#{bean.types}"
                        required="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select --" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.types}" var="type"
                            itemLabel="#{type}" itemValue="#{type}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Type(Enum):

```
D("Doctor"), R("Resident"), I("Instructor");

    private String type;

    private Type(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private Type type;

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public List<String> getTypes() {
        List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Type t : Type.values())
            types.add(t.getType());

        return types;
    }
```

Well, I don't know why, but in the parte of the "Select One Menu" is appearing an input text and a list. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Since, I can't post the photo here..

The link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gnmgolurk51f680/Annoying.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You have to change value attribute to `<p:selectOneMenu id="type" name="type" value="#{bean.type}"
                        required="true">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `<h:head/>` in your view file. Primefaces looks for this tag and puts its components (CSS and JS) inside.

Please read my previous comment for setting up the `p:selectonemenu`. Maybe you have a mistake.